# How to call a HttpPost ActionResult from a view in another controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show my login form in Home Index view,
and when user clicks the login button i want to authenticate him with an action result called (Login) in my Account controller..

### this is my code in Home Index view :

```
@model Charity.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{    

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
</div>


<input type="submit" value="Login" />

}
```

And this is my Login method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "User or password is incorrect");
            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

The problem is : when the credentials are correct , the website redirects to /Admin/Index and this is ok ..
but when the credentials are wrong , website redirects to /Account/Login . and my login form is not in this address..
how can i force login actionresult to redirect to /Home/Index when the credentils are wrong ??

Comment: Show the full view (possibly you have nested forms)

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is my whole view code .. there is no more markup in my view

Comment: "show my login form in Home Index view" implies that you're embedding this view in, say, Index.cshtml; are you simply returning this view by itself from the Index action in the Home controller?

Comment: There must be (because you have declared a model). But if you have no other html elements, show the GET and POST methods

Comment: Are your Login methods clearly marked with HttpGet and HttpPost attribute?

Comment: my Home Index view is using : 
@model Charity.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel

i edited the main code ..

Comment: @TiesonT. , yes im calling the view from my Index Actionresult in my HomeController

Comment: @MohamadRezaNazari What you mean by "calling"? Are you using something like `return View("login", "account")`, or are you using the HtmlHelper within the Home.cshtml view?

Comment: Your not returning your model - it needs to be `return View(model);`

Comment: It's not a case of "website redirects to /Account/Login"; you POSTed to that URL, so that's your new location. As @StephenMuecke says, you aren't including the model with the view you return on a failed login, so you're losing the context of that model.

Comment: This is going to be an interesting case of "how much a original question can be changed". The comments and answer becomes invalid with large edit to original post.

Answer (score 0):

Other than an extra closing `</div>` tag that doesn't appear to belong to any opening tag, your view seems valid.

What is most likely happening is that you decorated your AccountController with the `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    /* your code */
}
```

If you do that, you have to decorate any actions that **don't** need authorization with the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`. That includes the versions that are supposed to handle the POST event:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(Models.ViewModels.LoginModel model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    /* your code */
}
```

If you **don't** decorate the POST version with the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`, the `AuthorizeAttribute` is going to trigger a HTTP 401 result, and you get redirected to the login action.

Comment: thanks for your replies ..
please read the post again , my problem changed a little ..

Answer (score 0):

Thats my implemetation of the login method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null) // user.IsConfirmed
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If this point is reached , an error has occurred; Show form again .
        return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your return view() in login to

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")
```

the view will be home/index.cshtml ,but location address not change

and if in you home controller index action ,set data for view,it will run also in login action
if you want location change,use redirect and pass some param